# Node.js library to extract tables from PDF using JavaScript

Tags: gratis, library, javascript, pdf, node.js

I am looking for Node.js library for extracting tables from PDF files.

I have successfully used [tabula-java](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java) as a stand-alone application.

I have tried the following:

- Tried using [tabula-js](https://github.com/ezodude/tabula-js), which is a node wrapper for tabila-java. But didn't manage to make it work.

I am looking for free software options.

Answer (score 0):

I have an update on this question, I ended up cloning the repo "tabula-js" and changed some code.
It is fully working now

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/63696/edit) instead of posting edits as answers. You can delete this answer once you've updated your question.